# PCLStorage - How to get path to writable folder?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need download and save file. I using this code (with Xam.Plugins.DownloadManager and PCLStorage libraries):

```
public static string DownloadNewXml(string LinkToFile, string PathFile)
    {
        var downloadManager = CrossDownloadManager.Current;
        CrossDownloadManager.Current.PathNameForDownloadedFile = new System.Func<IDownloadFile, string>(file => {
           return PathFile;
        });
        try
        {
            var file = downloadManager.CreateDownloadFile(LinkToFile);
            downloadManager.Start(file);
            return "ok";
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return e.ToString() ;
        }
    }
```

Where PathFile is: FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage.Path + "file.xml";
This code throw exception on Android and UWP - i can't write file to this path (FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage.Path). So I have a question. How to get path to writable folder for my application on all platforms (Android, UWP, iOS)? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use `Path.Combine(FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage.Path, "file.xml")` instead

Comment: It's working for UWP. On Android throw exception: https://zapodaj.net/93c843db31fd5.png.html

Thank you for help :)

Comment: Got it. To use Android storage for write, you have to use external storage path. You can get it from Android project by DependencyService. This code will return you your local external storage app path: `Android.App.Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDir(null)`. It will return something like `/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.yourcompany.appname`

Comment: It's working! Thank you very much!
Btw. Why it isn't implemented in PCLStorage?

Comment: It's very platform-specific. iOS, for example, doesn't have external storage at all.