# System.UnauthorizedAccessException on Xamarin.Forms UWP Application

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp, data-synchronization

I am currently developping an UWP application using Xamarin.Forms framework and the PCL library.
I skip the details about the app but in a part of it, I want to duplicate a jpg file in a local directory, changing the name of the copied file.

Here is how I procede :

```
//Get the root folder from local storage
IFolder root = PCLStorage.FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
//Get work directory where jpg file is situated
IFolder work = await root.GetFolderAsync("work");

//Getting the jpg file from work folder
IFile currentPic = await work.GetFileAsync(currentCtrl.Id + ".jpg");

//Generating copy file's name
String tempFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".jpg";
//Create an empty file to write in
IFile copyFile = await work.CreateFileAsync(tempFileName,CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

//Process the copy
using (Stream outFileStream = await copyFile.OpenAsync(PCLStorage.FileAccess.ReadAndWrite))
using (Stream sourceStream = await currentPic.OpenAsync(PCLStorage.FileAccess.ReadAndWrite))
{
    await sourceStream.CopyToAsync(outFileStream, 81920);
}

//Trying to use the copy file
try
{
    using (Stream stream = await copyFile.OpenAsync(PCLStorage.FileAccess.ReadAndWrite))
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(copyFile.Name + " Successfully opened");
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

Problem is that when I run the debug, I have an exception thrown at line :
`using (Stream sourceStream = await currentPic.OpenAsync(PCLStorage.FileAccess.ReadAndWrite))`

Saying : "System.UnauthorizedAccessException : 'Access denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))'"

First, I have to tell you that my jpg file is coming from synchronization between local repository and NetExplorer remote repository.

File is uploaded on NetExplorer with an API call and is saved in my computer at the "work" repository thanks to synchro.

I suppose the synchro is the reason why access is denied but I am not sure.
I have tried to manually download jpg file and copy it into work repo and it did work.

Now I am stuck because I don't know how I can change file access autorization or find other solution (keeping in mind that I can't change the way I am getting the file from NetExplorer).

Huge thank you for your help.

**EDIT: The issue seems to be unrelated to the synchro. The issue appears only after using the PCLStorage MoveAsync function which is used to move a file from a directory to another one.**

Thomas

Comment: have you tried using just `Read` instead of `ReadAndWrite`?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes I have tried that but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PCLStorage - How to get path to writable folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43003818/pclstorage-how-to-get-path-to-writable-folder)

Comment: Hi ToolmakerSteve, not exactly but thank you for your help.

Comment: You can check this answer about [UWP Access to the path is denied.](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/xamarin-docs/issues/1287#issuecomment-450818598).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have checked what you sent but I suppose I don't have to use extra permission as my file is actually place in a folder inside the local repo of the app ?

Comment: Yes, that is right.